# Getting the List<string> of an XML file in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm quite new to android and am wondering how can I get the array of an XML file in android?

I've tried a lot of ways but all of them gave me a NullPointerException.

My directory of the xml folder is res/xml/db.xml

```
Document d = parseXML(this.getAssets().open("xml/db.xml"));
```

Is returning the 'File Not Found' exception.

And here's the parseXML method:

```
 public Document parseXML(InputStream f) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(false);
        dbf.setValidating(false);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        return db.parse(f);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, please let me know if this is any duplicate, because I've read several questions before and all of them couldn't help me enough! Thanks!

Comment: All I got was the FileNotFound exception when giving the f stream (I had it as File before)

Comment: I tried another way it gave me org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I used XMLPullParser and saved the xml files into a raw directory.

```
public static ArrayList<HModel> model_parse(InputStream url) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    final ArrayList<HModel> results = new ArrayList<HModel>(1000);

    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

    xpp.setInput(url, "UTF-8");

    xpp.nextTag();
    xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "NewDataSet");
    while (xpp.nextTag() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "Hispania_DB");
        HModel mdl = new HModel();
        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "Model");
        mdl.model = xpp.nextText();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "Model");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "Capacity");
        mdl.capacity = Double.parseDouble(xpp.nextText());
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "Capacity");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "Surface");
        mdl.surface = Double.parseDouble(xpp.nextText());
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "Surface");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "Air_x0020_Flow");
        mdl.airflow = xpp.nextText();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "Air_x0020_Flow");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "Air_x0020_Throw");
        mdl.airthrow = xpp.nextText();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "Air_x0020_Throw");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "Number_Fans");
        mdl.nm_fans = xpp.nextText();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "Number_Fans");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "Fan_Diameter");
        mdl.fandiam = xpp.nextText();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "Fan_Diameter");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "L");
        mdl.l = xpp.nextText();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "L");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "H");
        mdl.h = xpp.nextText();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "H");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "W");
        mdl.w = xpp.nextText();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "W");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "Weight");
        mdl.weight = xpp.nextText();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "Weight");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "Inlet");
        mdl.inlet = xpp.nextText();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "Inlet");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "Outlet");
        mdl.outlet = xpp.nextText();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "Outlet");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "Fan_x0020_Voltage");
        mdl.fan_volt = xpp.nextText();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "Fan_x0020_Voltage");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "Fan_x0020_Current");
        mdl.fan_curr = xpp.nextText();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "Fan_x0020_Current");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "Total_x0020_Defrost");
        mdl.defr = xpp.nextText();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "Total_x0020_Defrost");

        xpp.nextTag();
        xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "Hispania_DB");

        results.add(mdl);
    }
    xpp.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, "NewDataSet");

    return results;
}
```

And this worked perfectly, thanks guys though!

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a file arrays.xml under the **res/values** directory. Then you can add in your elements like:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="items">
    <item>lorem</item>
    <item >ipsum</item>
    <item >dolor</item>
    <item >sit</item>
    <item >amet</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

You can then access this as R.array.items

Comment: Let's consider I use this method, how can I retrieve the array? (There are several sub arrays)

Comment: I've never tried that out. Maybe you could nest them? I can try it out and post an update shortly...

Comment: I strongly prefer using xml though, and not string-array.